# blurred screen and focus issue in barcode scanner android 5.1

Tags: android, barcode-scanner, google-vision

barcode scanner in the samsung galaxy a6 tablet (android 5.1) device is showing blurred screen and focus issues while opening camera.I'm using google vision api.
Working fine with all other devices.Please help me out.